# Upload file directly to azure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I am writing a webpage that allows users to upload their files to Window Azure Storage.

First I let the user upload their files to my web-server, then I use Window Azure Storage API to upload these files to Window Azure Storage.

How can I let the user upload their files directly to Window Azure Storage without using my web-server as a proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can for instance do this using Silverlight as described here: http://blog.smarx.com/posts/uploading-windows-azure-blobs-from-silverlight-part-1-shared-access-signatures

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It solved my problem but not is perfect solution. Is there any other way that does not use ActiveX control as Silverlight, flash,...?

Answer (score 0):

The code at Steve Marx site doesn't work for large upload. I have posted a modified version of the control with cancellations and retries with Silverlight and TPL, also posted at WAZ portal at: [Silverlight and TPL based file upload control](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlight/Silverlight-Azure-Blob-3b773e26)
The project also has another version of the same control with HTML5 and AJAX.